# Selenium Python Chrome open with def options

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want open Google Chrome, like its self, the chromedriver open it without my cookies, my passwords, my history and all that staff.
i tried to play with the option, and search all over the web for solution,
didn't got one,
plus i tried

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

```
opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opt.add_arguments("--user-data-dir=C:\Users\Bar\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(opt)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

but it didn't work it says:

```
C:\Users\Bar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe C:/Users/Bar/PycharmProjects/yad2/Webdriver.py
  File "C:/Users/Bar/PycharmProjects/yad2/Webdriver.py", line 7
    opt.add_arguments("--user-data-dir=C:\Users\Bar\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")
                     ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 18-19: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Just omit `--` and try as `opt.add_arguments("user-data-dir=C:\Users\Bar\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")`

Comment: @SaurabhGaur Same error :\

Comment: i have tried to put r before the string to make it raw string its came now like this:`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Bar/PycharmProjects/yad2/Webdriver.py", line 6, in <module>
    opt.add_arguments(r"user-data-dir=C:\Users\Bar\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")
AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'add_arguments'`

Comment: @SaurabhGaur I have decided to copy the User Data to the Project folder , plus i have mistake with argument**s** , should be argument without **s** new problem: http://pastebin.com/Fr35Ph4y

Comment: I have provided it as an answer, try with this and let me know..:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'add_arguments'

It should be `add_argument` instead of `add_arguments`. You should try as :-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
opt.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\Users\Bar\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")
```

> AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'

Now you need to set this `opt` into `chrome_options` and pass it into `ChromeDriver` as :-

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opt)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

**Edited** :- You need to [download latest `chromedriver.exe`](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.23/) executable from here and extract this zip into at any location of your system and provide this path location with executable `chromedriver.exe` as `executable_path="path/to/chromedriver.exe"` and Initialize `ChromeDriver` as :-

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path/to/chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=opt)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

Comment: Well its working, but commands won't work like its doesn't open Google.com - @Saurabh Gaur

Comment: Did you download exetable ChromeDriver and set it into system path variable??

Comment: If you didn't download yet need to download chromedriver.exe and provide this path into ChromeDriver, try with edited answer and let me know..

Comment: i have chromedriver, its dropped in the project folder, so i dont need a path for it, after we add the opt, its open like a new window in the original chrome but it won't accept commands. plus the program is crash after a while of the project running like one minitue : http://pastebin.com/M998stCu
My final code till now:
`opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opt.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=C:\Users\Bar\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=opt)
driver.get("http://my.yad2.co.il/MyYad2/MyOrder/Car.php")`

Comment: @UnityNewb Please change this directory `C:\Users\Bar\AppData\Local\‌​Google\Chrome\User Data"` for `user-data-dir` to any other fresh location with empty folder and then try..

Comment: Thanks Work!, Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting the following error

SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 16-17: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

change all the backslashes to forward slashes like below

```
opt.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\Users\Bar\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")

opt.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:/Users/Bar/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data")
```

Comment: How does that relate to what OP is asking?

Answer (score 0):

A 2022 update, this worked to me:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
op.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=op)
```

Hope it will work for you too!